# Spread() error in anova_test(): how to make keys unique?

Tags: r, anova, spread

I'm trying to run a 2-way repeated measures ANOVA to look at condition and time effect on systolic BP. I'm using the `anova_test()` function but I'm getting the error:

```
Error in `spread()`:
! Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
ℹ Keys are shared for 6 rows
• 14, 36
• 182, 204
• 98, 120
```

I'm unsure of why these are reading as non-unique?

```
> df_lbp[c(14,36),]
# A tibble: 2 × 10
  subject_id condition visit  time  syst  timef      conditionf
       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <fct>      <fct>     
1        129         0     1     1  106.  anticipate Control   
2        165         1     1     1  119   anticipate Stress    
> df_lbp[c(182, 204),]
# A tibble: 2 × 10
  subject_id condition visit  time  syst  timef    conditionf
       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <fct>    <fct>     
1        129         0     1     3  103.  recovery Control   
2        165         1     1     3  121.  recovery Stress    
> df_lbp[c(98, 120),]
# A tibble: 2 × 10
  subject_id condition visit  time  syst  timef conditionf
       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>  <fct> <fct>     
1        129         0     1     2  102.  task  Control   
2        165         1     1     2  128   task  Stress
```

I'm curious what r is pulling from to use as keys, and I'd appreciate any help in getting this to work. My code and data are below.

```
a1 <- anova_test( data = df_lbp, dv = syst,
                  wid = subject_id, 
                  within = c(timef, conditionf) )

get_anova_table(a1)

 dput(df_lbp))
```

Comment: where is `anova_test` defined, are you using `rstatix`?

Comment: yes im using rstatix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You observation with `subject_id` 161 has several entries (varying `timef` values):

```
library(dplyr)

df_lbp |>
  count(subject_id, timef, conditionf) |>
  filter(n > 1)
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  subject_id timef      conditionf     n
       <dbl> <fct>      <fct>      <int>
1        161 anticipate Stress         2
2        161 task       Stress         2
3        161 recovery   Stress         2
```

... without these duplicates, `anova_test` runs OK:

```
df_lbp |>
  filter(subject_id != 161) |>
  rstatix::anova_test(dv = syst,
                      wid = subject_id, 
                      within = c(timef, conditionf)
                      )
```

output:

```
+ ANOVA Table (type III tests)

$ANOVA
            Effect DFn DFd      F        p p<.05   ges
1            timef   2  46 38.931 1.28e-10     * 0.076
2       conditionf   1  23 28.937 1.83e-05     * 0.284
3 timef:conditionf   2  46 37.078 2.57e-10     * 0.087
## etc.
```

**edit**
as r2evans pointed out, you can keep `distinct` combinations of variables (instead of checking first and singling them out) like so (note that the first/topmost observation of any duplicate is kept):

```
df_lbp |>
  distinct(subject_id, timef, conditionf,
           .keep_all = TRUE
           ) |>
  rstatix::anova_test(dv = syst,
                      wid = subject_id, 
                      within = c(timef, conditionf)
                      )
```

Comment: Nice find. I suggest a workaround that removes the duplicate entries vice all of `161` might be preferred.

Comment: I think the OP needs to consider whether `visit` should be part of the grouping parameters, since that id/timex/conditionf set includes two visits (1, 2) each.

Comment: thank you! I'm still curious about the output for the error, because the rows that it identified didn't correlate to subject 161. Was the way I searched for them wrong?

Comment: I ran `rlang::last_trace(drop = FALSE)` as suggested by the initial error message. From there it appeared that the fatal error occured *after* the actual `anova_test` at the stage where R tries to `spread` the anova results (not the initial data) into a tidy dataframe. So the `unique combination of keys` would refer to the *anova results*, rather than the original data. From there I took a guess that `timef` and `conditionf` might overlap at some observations.